# Arduino Char Array Mapping Overlap

Tags: c, char, arduino

I am trying to pass a string into a function in c and for some reason even though I have not set a value for the variable yet it already possesses the value of the other variable and if i change it, the changes seem to overwrite the other variable. Here is the code:

```
void reverse(char *s, char *reverse)
{
  uint32_t length = str_length(s);
  Serial.println(reverse);
  Serial.println(s);
  for (uint32_t i = 0; i < length; i++)
  {
    Serial.print(length - i - 1);
    Serial.println(s[length - i - 1]);
    reverse[i] = s[length - i - 1];
  }
  for (uint32_t i = 0; i < length; i++)
  {
    Serial.print(i);
    Serial.println(s[i]);
  }
  reverse[length] = '\0';
  Serial.println(reverse);
}

char* readstring()
{
  char s[128]; 
  readline(s, 128);
  return s;
}

char* str_reverse(char *r)
{
  char rev[128];
  reverse(r, rev);
  return rev;
}
```

`readstring()` is called earlier in the code and becomes the parameter r in `str_reverse`. Here is the output if I enter `face` as my string:

```
face
face
3e
2c
1c
0e
0e
1c
2c
3e
ecce
```

Why does it map the strings to the same memory slot?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

One major problem in your code is how you create the arrays `s` in `readstring()` and `rev` in `str_reverse()`. Both instances are created in the stack of the called function (thier respective funcitons) and would be freed upon return. The automatic 'freeing' (end of life time, by the language spec) will allow the new funciton to reuse the same memory for its stack. This gave you the illusion of the overlap.

For your testing, to see the other issues in your code, either use these arrays as `static` or global.

Comment: Ok that explains the reading overlap, but r is returned to the main function (and stored) and then used a parameter in str_reverse so why it being modified when i modify reverse?

Comment: Although making s global did solve my problem, so thank you for the solution.

Comment: We can spend time of why something like that happened, but really it's not very useful when it's a result of misuse/misunderstanding of the language. Once you return from the function, you can't grantee what could happen to the automatic variables that were declared in the function (i.e. placed in its stack).

Comment: Even if its stored if the return is stored again lower in the call stack?

Comment: You can't grantee the validity of the data upon your return. The specifics can depend on the implementation details but it's definitely not right. What I'd do, allocate (or use auto variable in your main) but pass it to your function which will fill it for you. Also, be careful `static` variable or global will make the function not multi-threaded safe (non-reentrant).